# SignalR doesn't work after updating to 2.1?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I just updated `jquery.signalR` in my project.
After updating signalr doesn't work anymore.
I enabled logging as the following :

```
  $.connection.hub.logging = true;
```

and the following is my siganlR log

```
[16:34:11 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'leecherhub'. jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
[16:34:11 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22leecherhub%22%7D%5D'. jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
[16:34:11 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://localhost:1758/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=oTO6pipUB4XMMRsQpYxz8gCote5oXgW60YUHHiZKfk2lmRrVAPAFyU6MUk1ahDvgFWnT08wmgNPvdIVBgHBP%2FsZtfKMJFJ2%2BjaqaFyahwVf9K3mZs3l9kG%2BF8wwCCO3B&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22leecherhub%22%7D%5D&tid=9'. jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
[16:34:12 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: Websocket opened. jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
[16:34:16 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: webSockets timed out when trying to connect. jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
[16:34:16 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: Closing the Websocket. jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
[16:34:17 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://localhost:1758/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProt…2BF8wwCCO3B&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22leecherhub%22%7D%5D&tid=2'. jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
[16:34:17 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource connected. jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
[16:34:22 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents timed out when trying to connect. jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
[16:34:22 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close(). jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
[16:34:22 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: This browser supports SSE, skipping Forever Frame. jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
[16:34:22 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: Opening long polling request to 'http://localhost:1758/signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&clientProtocol=…2BF8wwCCO3B&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22leecherhub%22%7D%5D&tid=3'. jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
[16:34:22 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: Long poll complete. jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
[16:34:22 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: Opening long polling request to 'http://localhost:1758/signalr/poll?transport=longPolling&messageId=d-76EB7D…2BF8wwCCO3B&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22leecherhub%22%7D%5D&tid=6'. jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
[16:34:27 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: longPolling timed out when trying to connect. jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
[16:34:27 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: Aborted xhr request. jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
[16:34:27 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: Stopping connection. jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js:81
[16:34:27 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)] SignalR: Fired ajax abort async = true.
```

What's the problem?

**Edit:**
My signalr connected seldom, but most of the time above error occur

Comment: Need more info, was it upgrade from 1.0 to 2.1 or 2.0 or 2.1? 1 -> 2 had some larger breaking changes, 2 -> 2.1 had a minor breaking change. I myself was unable to get a 2 -> 2.1 upgrade working so I just dropped back down to 2.0 :/ but anyone who could help will need to know the version. I would also recommend google breaking changes for your version upgrade.

Comment: @Tony: The previous version was 2.0.3

Comment: This may help, it did not for me unfortunately. https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/releases top section has breaking changes. Interested to see what responses you get as I wouldn't mind attempting the upgrade again the client contracts appeal to me :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug. 
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3148
The problem will solve by updating to SignalR 2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

very likely your problem was a bug reported here https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3116

I have the same issue and I think the 2.1 is a bad release. I ended up rolling back to 2.0.3